# SAP process session txt no taking input column

Tags: sap-erp

We have an excel vba that generates a txt in order to make postings faster.

However, there is field that is not taking the field even if it is generated in the txt:

[image]

As you can see, when checking in SAP how it is doing with the txt we can see it is in blank (see in yellow below):

[image]

Do you have any ideas why it is leaving in blank? Maybe field name is wrong?

Any sugestion will be really apreaciated.

Thank you all and best regards,

Alfonso

Comment: It's not a programming question, so you should better post it to [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Comment: Ok I will post there. I have posted here because I have programmed the vba code and I am having an error. However I am not saying nothing about the code because I think the error is more about terminology or something similar. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed in the macro that generates the txt to use:

RKEAK-FIELD(08) instead of COBL-WEARKS and in screen SAPLKEAK0300X

Now it is working!